# Writing to firebase from dispatch results in duplicate rows

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dispatch, use-reducer

I am playing with a simple app that displays a collection of Posts from firebase and allows the user to add docs to it.
The posts are shared via a PostsContext that contains an ADD function. The useReducer gets called twice, no getting around that. The problem is that I'm writing to firebase from inside the ADD, and this results in duplicate rows.

```
export const PostsContext = React.createContext();

export const PostsProvider = function ({ children }) {
const reducer = function (state, action) {
switch (action.type) {
  case "ADD": {
    const newPost = {
      id: id(),
      title: action.payload.title,
      content: action.payload.comment,
    };

    console.log("THIS GETS CALLED TWICE");
    firestore.collection("posts").add(newPost);

    return [newPost, ...state];
  }

  case "INIT": {
    console.log(action.payload);
    return [...action.payload.posts];
    }
  }
 return state;
};

const [posts, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

const addPost = function (title, comment) {
dispatch({
  type: "ADD",
  payload: {
    title,
    comment,
  },
 });
};

const initPosts = function (posts) {
dispatch({
  type: "INIT",
  payload: {
    posts,
  },
});
};

 const value = { posts, addPost, initPosts };
 return (
  <PostsContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</PostsContext.Provider>
);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to write to the DB in AddPost **before** calling dispatch.
That's all.